# `isMovingToParentViewController`/`isMovingToParent` incorrectly true

Tags: swift, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit

In my view controller, I am checking for `isMovingToParent` inside `viewWillAppear` so that I can execute some logic only when the view controller is first displayed and **not** when a later view controller is popped off the stack to reveal my original one.

I would expect this value to be `true` when the VC is first pushed onto the navigation stack and `false` when it appears because of a later VC popping off the stack.

However, in both cases, the value ends up being `true`. Any reason why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Are you overriding any of the `didMove(toParent:)`/`willMove(toParent:)` methods? If so, make sure you are calling `super`'s version of that method. If you fail to do so, the `isMovingToParent` series of properties seemingly can be incorrectly set.

Note: If anyone has documentation attesting to the above behaviour, please edit the answer :)

Comment: Edited the answer to remove that. I added it because I didn't feel I could declaratively state that this is the only reason why my scenario in the question would happen.

I realise now if someone else has other situations where this can happen, they can simply offer their own answer.